# browserify, karma, jasmine and gulp not running tests even after setting config

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine

I followed the instructions here https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-browserify and even after setting the karma.conf.js with the following it does not run any tests in PhantomJS or Chrome. It says `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR` even though I have one dummy spec file in test folder which passes.

```
  karma.set({
    basePath: 'to/some/somepath'
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine' ],
    files: ['relative/to/somepath/test/**/*.js'],
    preprocessors: {
      'relative/to/somepath/test/**/*.js': ['browserify']
    },

    browserify: {
      debug: true
    }
  });
```